# [[deprecated]] + __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) in GCC 6.2

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, visibility, deprecated

Combining the `[[deprecated]]` and the `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` attributes with `-std=c++14` generate errors (different depending on the order used `expected identifier before ‘__attribute__’` or `expected identifier before ‘[’ token`).
Using them separately does not generate the errors.

The c++11 style attribute `[[gnu::visibility("default")]]` works for classes, but not for functions (the code compiles, but produces a `-Wattributes` warning and the symbol is left out when built with `-fvisibility=hidden`).

Is this a bug in the compiler (I used GCC 6.2 for these tests) or something specified by c++ standard? The same code (`[[deprecated]] __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`) works as expected using clang).

This is the code I used for my tests to combine all the possibilities, the only cases that produce the wanted result (deprecated + default visibility) are 3 and 7, i.e. the ones using the old style attributes.

`foo.h`

```
#if defined(X_VERSION)
#  if (X_VERSION % 4) == 0        //  0   4   8  12
#    define DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
#    define VISIBILITY [[gnu::visibility("default")]]
#  elif (X_VERSION % 4) == 1      //  1   5   9  13
#    define DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
#    define VISIBILITY __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#  elif (X_VERSION % 4) == 2      //  2   6  10  14
#    define DEPRECATED __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#    define VISIBILITY [[gnu::visibility("default")]]
#  elif (X_VERSION % 4) == 3      //  3   7  11  15
#    define DEPRECATED __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#    define VISIBILITY __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#  else
#    error "Invalid X_VERSION"
#  endif

#  if (X_VERSION / 4) == 0        //  0   1   2   3
#    define DEPRECATED_API DEPRECATED VISIBILITY
#  elif (X_VERSION / 4) == 1      //  4   5   6   7
#    define DEPRECATED_API VISIBILITY DEPRECATED
#  elif (X_VERSION / 4) == 2      //  8   9  10  11
#    define DEPRECATED_API DEPRECATED
#  elif (X_VERSION / 4) == 3      // 12  13  14  15
#    define DEPRECATED_API VISIBILITY
#  else
#    error "Invalid X_VERSION"
#  endif
#else
#  error "X_VERSION not defined"
#endif

#if defined(DEPRECATED_API)
#  define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#  define STR(x) #x
#  pragma message "DEPRECATED_API = " XSTR(DEPRECATED_API)
#endif

class DEPRECATED_API foo
{
public:
    foo();
    virtual ~foo();
    void test();

    int a;
};

void DEPRECATED_API a_function();
```

`foo.cpp`

```
#include <foo.h>

foo::foo() {}
foo::~foo() {}
void foo::test() {}

void a_function() {}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(test_lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)


foreach(i RANGE 0 15)
  if(i LESS 10)
    set(target_name foo_v0${i})
  else()
    set(target_name foo_v${i})
  endif()
  add_library(${target_name} SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
  target_compile_definitions(${target_name} PRIVATE X_VERSION=${i})
endforeach()
```

Comment: Just for completeness, this fails also passing the option `-std=gnu++14`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of time, I found that:

```
void [[deprecated]] [[gnu::visibility("default")]] a_function();
```

should have been:

```
 [[deprecated]] [[gnu::visibility("default")]] void a_function();
```

In this case, both version 0 and 4 work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nearly identical problem with class file definitions that required a different solution. The following class file signature failed to compile with Apple clang version 12.0.0:

```
class [[deprecated]] __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) OldGuy {
public:
    void saySomething() {
        std::cout << "I'm Deprecated!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The failure message is as follows:

```
error: declaration of anonymous class must be a definition"
[[deprecated]] __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) OldGuy {
^
```

I was able to resolve the issue by switching the order of the visibility and deprecated attributes as follows:

```
class __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) [[deprecated]] OldGuy {
public:
    void saySomething() {
        std::cout << "I'm Deprecated!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I found this to be a compiler dependent issue associated with clang version 12.0.0, the latest available from Xcode on Big Sur. When compiling with Apple clang version 13.1.6 from Xcode on Monterey, the code compiles successfully regardless of the order of the deprecated and visibility attributes.

Furthermore, using a modern attribute syntax of [[deprecated, visibility("default")]] also compiles successfully on both clang 12.0.0 and 13.1.6. According to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569621/is-there-a-difference-between-attribute-some-attribute-and-some-attr), this is the standard attribute syntax. I unfortunately am working with a legacy code base (Juce) that uses a macro to control visibility in a manner incompatible with this standard syntax.