# Is there a difference between `__attribute__((some_attribute))` and `[[some_attribute]]`?

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes

I just came across attributes enclosed in square brackets for the first time, and I've been doing a little background reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes.

For gcc at least, there seem to be multiple techniques allowed:

```
__attribute__((some_attribute))
```

and

```
[[some_attribute]]
```

Is this correct? When is one technique allowed or not allowed, preferred or not preferred? What's the difference?

It looks like `[[some_attribute]]` is allowed as of C++11 only, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *N4659*:

> 10.6.1 Attribute syntax and semantics [dcl.attr.grammar]
>
> Attributes specify additional information for various source
>   constructs such as types, variables, names, blocks, or translation
>   units.
>
> ```
> attribute-specifier-seq:
>     attribute-specifier-seqopt attribute-specifier
>
> attribute-specifier: 
>     [ [ attribute-using-prefixopt attribute-list ] ]
>     alignment-specifier
> ```

So, `[[...]]` is a standardized syntax.

In opposite, `__attribute__ ((attribute-list))` is a syntax of `gcc` [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html):

> An attribute specifier is of the form `__attribute__ ((attribute-list))`. An attribute list is a possibly empty comma-separated sequence of attributes, where each attribute is one of the following:
>
> ...

As attributes were introduced in *C++11* and you use `gcc` with *C++11* support (or newer), then both types of syntax are available for you.

Comment: Quick follow-up: can I place the attribute before OR after a function name, for example the attribute `[[noreturn]]`? `[[noreturn]] void foo();` or `void foo() [[noreturn]];`?

Comment: @GabrielStaples the first usage is correct, the second - isn't.

Comment: Thanks! I just spent about 15 min or so and checked it. With the first usage when I compile with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 no_return_practice.cpp` it compiles and says `warning: ‘noreturn’ function does return [enabled by default]`. When I run it it crashes before it prints anything after this call. I guess this is the specified behavior---because the function never returns. So that usage works. With the 2nd usage I get a compiler warning that states `warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]  void foo() [[noreturn]]...`, and the program runs as normal, which means the attribute did NOT work.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, at first when I gave Edgar Rokjan the "correct answer" I felt bad because yours was first and is also correct. I don't feel bad anymore. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `[[foo]]` syntax was introduced with C++11. But many compilers had their own syntax before that (which in some cases also supports some non-standardized attributes).

So in short: `[[foo]]` is standard and should work everywhere with a conforming compiler. The other syntaxes are compiler specific.

Comment: Attributes in the C++11 standard format are namespaced. So the GCC-specific __attribute_((foo)) is equivalent to [[gnu::foo]