# Old-style vs C++11 attribute syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

By old-style I mean `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`

By C++11 syntax I mean `[[gnu::visibility("default")]]`

I am working on huge codebase which must stay buildable with MSVC, GCC and Clang.
Recently I have noticed that we can't mix C++11 style deprecation attribute with old-style visibility attribute.
Example: https://godbolt.org/z/do9f4446Y.

Which means we have to either stick to the old-style syntax for attributes everywhere, or we should switch whole codebase to new syntax.

This leads me to a question: What style of attributes is preferred in modern C++ projects? It seems majority of C++ code on github is still using old-style attributes, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569621/is-there-a-difference-between-attribute-some-attribute-and-some-attr

Comment: *"for attributes everywhere"* As your example show, you might have both, the only restriction is to not mix them for the same "place".

Comment: *"old style"* is an extension syntax...

Answer (score 0):

New-style is preferred — unless you need C++98 compatibility, in which case (as of this writing, in 2024) you're stuck with `__attribute__` on GCC. (Clang 17+, OTOH, finally supports new-style `[[]]` attributes in C++98 mode. Although it seems to have [a bug](https://godbolt.org/z/bMoKTsc38) with the `[[gnu::visibility("foo")]]` spelling...)

One quirk that caught me by surprise: Vendor-specific new-style attributes get a vendor prefix, as in `[[clang::trivial_abi]]` or `[[gnu::pure]]`. But the old-style syntax (as of 2024) still hasn't been updated to accept prefixes — so those attributes are spelled in the old style `__attribute__((trivial_abi))` and `__attribute__((pure))` respectively. You just drop the prefix. That's arguably a reason to prefer the new style: it's got a proper place to put that prefix and thus distinguish vendor-specific attributes from standard ones!

In your Godbolt you wrote:

```
// works, but old deprecation attribute does not supports string-parameter
class
  __attribute__((visibility("default")))
  __attribute__((deprecated))
  IOpenGLRenderingPipelineAccess3 {};
```

You must have been holding it wrong; the parameteriferous syntax works fine for me, all the way back to Clang 3.0 (i.e. the beginning of time) and GCC 4.5 (but starting sometime after GCC 4.1).

```
// OK, works great
class
  __attribute__((visibility("default")))
  __attribute__((deprecated("ASDF")))
  IOpenGLRenderingPipelineAccess3 {};
```